# 配列のsizeof()

Tags: c++

c++のVectorなのですがこの`vector<int> x(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));`
の a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])の　a + とはどのような意味なのでしょうか？
sizeof()によって配列aの要素数が求められるのはわかるのですがそれがなぜa + されるのでしょうか？初歩的質問で申し訳ないのですが教えていただけますでしょうか？

```
        #include <vector>
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
                          //ここです。
            vector<int> x(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); // 配列からベクトルを生成

            try {
                for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                    cout << "x[" << i << "] = " << x.at(i) << '\n';
                }
            }
            catch (const out_of_range&) {
                cout << "不正な添字です。\n";
                return 1;                           // 強制終了
            }
        }
```

Comment: `a` は vector ではなく生の配列なので、質問タイトルは「vectorのsizeof()」というよりか「配列のsizeof()を足すとどうなる？」のようなものにした方が意図が伝わりやすいなと思いました。

Comment: 適当な長さの配列 `a` に対して、`a + 1` が何を意味するかはご存じですか？

Comment: 知らないので教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: C++0x で [std::end](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iterator/end.html) が導入されましたので、`vector<int> x(a, end(a));` と書ける様になりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define elementsof(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
```

は（提示コードの `sizeof` の除算式部分をマクロ化したものですけど） [c](/questions/tagged/c) 互換の単純配列の要素数を `size_t` 型で返すイディオムです。これが要素数 (提示例では `5` ) を返す理由は今回説明略（必要なら別途質問を挙げてくれると幸いです）。

一方で、ここで `x` を構築している `std::vector` のコンストラクタは
https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/vector/op_constructor.html
の (5) で、単純配列の開始位置 `first` と終了位置 `last` を指定するものです。

`last` が開区間つまり `last` 自体は初期値に含まれないことは厳に理解が必要です。

さてコメント上での質疑応答 `int a[5];` があるとき `a+1` あるいは `a+5` の意味は？ ですが・・・ここんところは [c](/questions/tagged/c) の配列取り扱い上の基礎中の基礎で、

- 配列名は、特定文脈を除き [配列の最初の要素へのポインタ右辺値] に読み替えられる
- 配列要素を指すポインタに加減算を行うと、要素１つ分の移動である

前者により `a` は `&a[0]` に半自動で変換されます。後者によりこれに `+1` すれば `(&a[0])+1` つまり `&a[1]` であることを（この質疑応答で納得できなければいろいろ検索してみて）理解してください。そして更に

- `a[5]` は存在しない要素なので、これをアクセスすることは違反だが `&a[5]` を演算することは認められている

のも知ってください (JIS X 3014:2003 5.7 加減演算子) これにより

```
std::vector<int> x(a, a+5); // 提示例の sizeof 除算式は要素数でしたよね
```

は `a` という配列の `a[0]` から `a[4]`　の５つの値を初期値とする `std::vector` の構築ということになります。この書き方で

- `&a[5]` と書くことができるが
- `a[5]` にアクセスすることはないので未定義動作にならない
- 値 `5` は `sizeof` 式で求めるようにすると、要素数の変更に自動的に追従できる

そもそも論として

```
for (i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

を `for (i=0; i<=4; ++i)` と書かないのと同じで [c](/questions/tagged/c) で配列を扱う際には半開区間を使うのが自然であるため `vector` のコンストラクタも半開区間を採用しています。

`&a[5]` を演算すること自体を違反にすると

```
for (p=&a[0]; p<&a[5]; ++p) printf("%d\n", *p);
```

と書けなくなっちゃいますよね。