# 原因のわからないコンパイラエラーメッセージ

Tags: c++

for文の場所でこのようなコンパイルエラーが出ます。
[重大度レベル コード 説明  プロジェクト  ファイル    行   抑制状態
エラー C2760   構文エラー: トークン '識別子' は予期されておらず、';' が予期されています   main.cpp 18行]
再度確認しプロジェクトを作り直したりソフトの再起動もしましたがエラーがとれません。
参考書は明解c++中級編です。環境はWindows10 visual studio 2017です
hello worldを実行して文字を表示したりしてるのでプロジェクトの作り間違えの可能性はないと思います、またヘッダーやソースファイルもmain.cppしか作ってないのでやはり構文エラーだと思うのですがやはりわかりません。教えていただけますでしょうか。？

```
#include "conio.h"
//#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



template <class T, class Allocator>
void print_vector(const vector<T, Allocator>& v)
{
    cout << "{ ";
                          /*この行です↓*/
    for (vector<T,Allocator>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << '}';
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> x(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));

    double b[] = { 3.5, 7.3, 2.2, 9.9 };
    vector<double> y(b, b + sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]));

    string c[] = { "abc", "WXYZ", "123456" };
    vector<string> z(c, c + sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]));

    cout << "x = ";   print_vector(x);   cout << '\n';
    cout << "y = ";   print_vector(y);   cout << '\n';
    cout << "z = ";   print_vector(z);   cout << '\n';

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GNU C++ ですと、`error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type’ because ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>’ is a dependent scope` というエラーメッセージが表示されます。なぜ `typename` というキーワードが必要なのかは…その参考書に書いてあるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 明解c++中級編374ページを読んでいますが説明がないので困っています。コードをダウンロードしてきてコピペしました。(自分でも確認しまいた)本の著者様のサイトに間違いや訂正がないか見ましたが準備中でみれませんでした。

Comment: ロールバックしました。[回答を得た後で別の質問に書き換えないで](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2601/4236)ください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual C++は[コンパイルオプション`/permissive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance)で次の２つの構文パーサを切り替えて選択することができます。

- 従来互換でC++標準に準拠しない構文パーサ（`/permissive`もしくは未指定）
- C++標準に準拠した構文パーサ（`/permissive-`）

コンパイラそのものは前者がデフォルトですが、Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5以降を使用してプロジェクトを新規に作成した場合に後者が選択されるようあらかじめ構成されています。

プロジェクトの設定を変更しコンパイルオプション`/permissive-`を無効化することで従来互換の構文パーサが有効になり、件のエラーは指摘されなくなります。
想像ですが、著者はC++標準を知らないままテキトーに書籍を執筆されたものと思われます。

正しくはmetropolisさんがコメントされているように、以下のように`typename`キーワードが必要です。`typename`キーワードを追加した場合は、`/permissive`、`/permissive-`どちらの構文パーサを使用してもコンパイルに成功します。

```
for (typename vector<T,Allocator>::size_type i = 0; i != v.size(); i++)
{
    cout << v[i] <<" ";
}
```

---

なお今時であれば、挙げられているような面倒なコードは書かず、[C++11](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11.html)の[範囲for文](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/range_based_for.html)と[`auto`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/auto.html)の機能を使用して

```
for (auto const& val : v)
    cout << val << " ";
```

と書きます。

勉強されるのでしたら、標準に準拠した、時代に即した書籍を参照されることをお勧めします。
そうでない場合、まず著者の指定するコンパイラを使用するべきです。また質問の際にいつの時代について取り扱いたいのかを明示していただく必要があります。例えば、[別スレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47855/%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AEsizeof#comment49361_47855)でmetropolisさんが`std::end()`を提案されていますがVisual C++で`std::end()`が使えるのは[Visual Studio 2012以降](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/jj190751(v%3Dvs.110))となります。2012未満を前提に書かれた書籍を参考にされた場合は`std::end()`は登場せず混乱することでしょう。

Comment: 2014/3/25が自分が今使ってる参考書の発行日なのですが、はやり数年でも内容が変わるのでもっと最新の本を使ったほうがいいのでしょうか？多少時間がたってても大きくは変わらないだろうと思い買いました。

Comment: @beginner そもそも当該書籍は2014年に書かれたものなのでしょうか？ 遥か昔に書かれた書籍の「新版」≒焼き直しではありませんか？ 例えば回答で挙げた「範囲for文」や「auto」は当該書籍で扱われていますでしょうか？ これらが含まれていない場合、C++11に未対応で2003年頃のC++03の内容ということになってしまいます。

Comment: 本の最初のページに平成26年三月とあり参考書の中でテンプレートのエクスポート機能を削除されているので使えませんとか注意してあるのでですがどうなのでしょうか？

Comment: @beginner 私は当該書籍を持っていないのでわかりません。が、その記述は単に動かない部分の言い訳にしか聞こえません。「C++11対応」等の記載がなければC++03（酷い場合はC++98）の内容と考えるべきです。

Comment: [この書籍](http://www.bohyoh.com/Books/MeikaiCPP02/index.html)ですかね。著者は「標準C++（ISO／ANSI／JIS規格）に完全対応しています。」と述べていますね。追記：あれ？著者の言葉ではないのかな？